# Rotation Snapping Back To Zero

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My code below rotates an object and moves them based on the angle of the joystick on the controller:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerControllerTEST : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float moveSpeed;
    public float h;
    public float v;
    public float moveX;
    public float moveZ;
    public Rigidbody rb;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        moveX = (h * moveSpeed) * Time.deltaTime;
        moveZ = (v * moveSpeed) * Time.deltaTime;

        transform.Translate(moveX, 0f, moveZ, Space.World);

        Quaternion rotate = Quaternion.Euler(0f, (Mathf.Atan2(h, v) * Mathf.Rad2Deg), 0f);

        Debug.Log(rotate);

        rb.MoveRotation(rotate);
    }
}
```

However when I let go of the joystick, the object is snapping back to an angle of 0 degrees. I'm not sure how I would get it to keep the angle before the joystick is essentially let go.

Comment: Depending on the smoothing of the input axis Unity does for you (`GetAxis()` vs `GetAxisRaw()`) you could try `if(Mathf.Abs(h) <= epsilon && Mathf.Abs(v) <= epsilon) return;` after rotating with `epsilon` being a small value like `0.1f`, i.e., just don't rotate when `h` and `v` are small enough.

Comment: I used this following block of code - `if(Mathf.Abs(h) > 0){previousH = h;}if(Mathf.Abs(v) > 0){previousV = v;}` then changed a line above to - `Quaternion rotate = Quaternion.Euler(0f, (Mathf.Atan2(previousH, previousV) * Mathf.Rad2Deg), 0f);` which seems to hold the rotation well. The only thing is now to smooth the rotation to the new position. But that's another question!